# Unir dos Inner Join en un Full Join .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

estoy intentado hacer un full join para mandar a llamar el id de diferentes tablas

```
 var pais = from elemento in db.CostoFR
                       join trafico in db.Trafico
                       on elemento.Id_Trafico equals trafico.Id
                       join operador in db.Operador on elemento.Id_Operador equals operador.Id
                       where elemento.Activo == 1 && elemento.Id_LineaNegocio == lineaNegocio

                       join moneda in db.Moneda
                       on elemento.Id_Moneda equals moneda.Id
                       join operador in db.Operador on elemento.Id_Operador equals operador.Id
                       where elemento.Activo == 1 && elemento.Id_LineaNegocio == lineaNegocio
                       select new
                       {
                           elemento.Id,
                           operador.Id_Operador,
                           moneda.Moneda1,
                           trafico.Id_traficoTR,
                           elemento.Importe,
                           elemento.Fecha_Inicio,
                           elemento.Fecha_Fin,
                           elemento.Id_CR
                       };
```

tengo esto pero la verdad no se como puedo unir esos dos joins para gener una sola consulta en un grid

Answer (score 0):

Podrias ser algo como esto

```
var pais = from elemento in db.CostoFR
           join trafico in db.Trafico on elemento.Id_Trafico equals trafico.Id
           join operador in db.Operador on elemento.Id_Operador equals operador.Id
           join moneda in db.Moneda on elemento.Id_Moneda equals moneda.Id
           where elemento.Activo == 1 && elemento.Id_LineaNegocio == lineaNegocio
           select new
           {
               elemento.Id,
               operador.Id_Operador,
               moneda.Moneda1,
               trafico.Id_traficoTR,
               elemento.Importe,
               elemento.Fecha_Inicio,
               elemento.Fecha_Fin,
               elemento.Id_CR
           };
```

Basicamente quite el `join` que relacionaba dos veces a `operador` y deja solo un `where`

Comment: gracias me salvaste la vida :)